# Singleton design pattern which to be used when?

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
// Lazy Initialization 

Public MySingleton{
    private static mySingleton = null;

    Public Static getInstance(){
       if(null == mySingleton ){
            mySingleton = new MySingleton();
       }

       return mySingleton;
    }
}
```

---

```
// Eager Initilization 

Public MySingleton{
    private static mySingleton = new MySingleton();

    Public Static getInstance(){
        return mySingleton ;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Your first example will create a new instance every time you try to get *the* instance.  I'm assuming that's not what you want.

Comment: It best to have a compiling example first which behaves correctly before worrying about best practice.

Comment: @ I have corrected the code . Sorry for trouble .

Comment: lazy causes problems or at least opens the door for them (multi-threading). So it is best to use the "eager" example you have.

Comment: I don't understand why this got closed. I think this is a valid question (lazy vs. eager initialization). Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Both are incorrect.  You should follow the example set in Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java", explained [here](http://electrotek.wordpress.com/2008/08/06/singleton-in-java-the-proper-way/), based on enum.

Comment: Yes, both of them do not handle concurrency very well.

Answer (score 2):

As java has moved in the direction of dependency injection, I've seen less and less explicit singletons like what is described above. This is because when an IOC container instantiates an object it's by default a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

The first is an attempt at optimization:

- If you know your code takes a long time to initialize, but is rarely used, you should use lazy.
- If you know your code takes a long time to initialize, but is not used till quite a while later in the program, use lazy.
- If profiling reveals under rare circumstances the singleton is actually used, use lazy.

There's more situations... this should give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is not a singleton at all. It returns a new instance on every call!

That said, which is "better" (lazy vs. eager) really depends on your circumstances. Lazy is more complicated, which is its main liability.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use an enumeration.

   public enum Foo {
       INSTANCE;
   }
```

Read this from [`Effective Java,`](http://drdobbs.com/java/208403883?pgno=3)

> "This approach is functionally
>   equivalent to the public field
>   approach, except that it is more
>   concise, provides the serialization
>   machinery for free, and provides an
>   ironclad guarantee against multiple
>   instantiation, even in the face of
>   sophisticated serialization or
>   reflection attacks. While this
>   approach has yet to be widely adopted,
>   a single-element enum type is the best
>   way to implement a singleton."

Comment: The approach is bad, regardless if Josh pushes it. Singletons are used (usually) as interfaces for the client code, so what: enum will implement the interface... and then it's still serializable. Hence if an object is serialized and then deserialized in a different process w/ a different singleton instance - bam, no more singleton (2 instances). The entire idea that a singleton should be serializable is horrid. To top the issue: enums serialization cannot be controlled by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid duplicates with a singleton is to do the following:

```
public final MySingleton {

  //this will be instantiated at class loading time, thus insuring more than one thread
  //won't get separate instances.
  private static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();

  private MySingleton() {
    //empty for this example.
  }

  public static MySingleton getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```